# Notepad++ Directory Replacing

Tags: notepad++

I need some help
I have a url like this
https://developers.apple.com/forums/profile/ShadowDES/Boy?view=FUZZ

What i want is to replace each directory with a specific keyword i.e XYZ

```
https://developers.apple.com/XYZ/profile/ShadowDES/Boy?view=32
https://developers.apple.com/forums/XYZ/ShadowDES/Boy?view=32
https://developers.apple.com/forums/profile/XYZ/Boy?view=32
```

Means if there are 3 directory, output should be with 3 urls

I have a list of url, is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for URL with up to 5 directories. If you have more than 5, add as many `(.+?/)?` as needed and update the group numbers in the replacement accordingly.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(https?://.+?/)(.+?/)(.+?/)?(.+?/)?(.+?/)?(.+?/)?(\S+)`
- Replace with: `$1XYZ/$3$4$5$6$7\n(?3$1$2XYZ/$4$5$6$7\n)(?4$1$2$3XYZ/$5$6$7\n)(?5$1$2$3$4XYZ/$6$7\n)(?6$1$2$3$4$5XYZ/$7)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(https?://.+?/)     # group 1, domain, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy & slash
(.+?/)              # group 2, 1rst dir, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy & slash
(.+?/)?             # optional group 3, 2nd dir, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy & slash
(.+?/)?             # same for group 4
(.+?/)?             # same for group 5
(.+?/)?             # same for group 6
(\S+)               # group 7, rest of the URL
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1XYZ/$3$4$5$6$7\n          # replace group 2 (1rst dir) with XYZ
(?3$1$2XYZ/$4$5$6$7\n)      # if group 3 exists, replace group 3 (2nd dir) with XYZ
(?4$1$2$3XYZ/$5$6$7\n)      # if group 4 exists, replace group 4 (3rd dir) with XYZ
(?5$1$2$3$4XYZ/$6$7\n)      # if group 5 exists, replace group 5 (4th dir) with XYZ
(?6$1$2$3$4$5XYZ/$7)        # if group 6 exists, replace group 6 (5th dir) with XYZ
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: You are really a pro of notepad, it helps me alot <3 great explanation

Comment: @HelloFresh01: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)